# How to start a Maven project from command line, when using a local repository?

Tags: java, maven

I have a Maven project in which I need to use a dependency that is local. To include it in the project, in `pom.xml` I do:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>com.something.library</groupId>
        <artifactId>theId</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
        <scope>system</scope>
        <systemPath>C:/Tests/libs/something.jar</systemPath>
</dependency>
```

When I build and run the project through the IntelliJ IDE, the project starts normally and runs as expected. However, when I do:

```
mvn compile
mvn exec:java -D"exec.mainClass"="org.example.Main"
```

I'm prompted with the information, that one of the classes from within that jar package, can't be found (again, that was not the case when I tried running through IDE).

Am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: I suggest you don't fight this and install the jar in your local repository.  Many tutorials exist for this, e.g. https://www.baeldung.com/install-local-jar-with-maven

Comment: @AndrewL That did the trick. I still wonder why my approach didn't work though. Maybe you can post your comment as a response, so I can mark it as a solution to this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try installing the JAR in you local Repo. Many tutorials exist for this, e.g. [baeldung.com/install-local-jar-with-maven](https://baeldung.com/install-local-jar-with-maven)

TBH I have never used

```
        <scope>system</scope>
        <systemPath>C:/Tests/libs/something.jar</systemPath>
```

Only examples I have seen are relative to the project root.  Remove the `C:` ... perhaps it is something about jumping from one drive to another in Windows??